# How can I make my selected outstanding in the form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two questions in the  tag. I want to highlight the answer I chose by changing the background color. However, it is possible for me to do this because when I choose the answer in the first question, then I choose the next question, the highlight in the previous one disappears. So now, how I can do that, and how I can choose my answer by click anywhere in the answer box instead of clicking on the label or the radio box.

```js
function openPresent(event) {

    const answer = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
    for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        answer[i].style.backgroundColor = originalAnswerArray[i];
    }

    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

}

const answer = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
let i;

let originalAnswerArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    originalAnswerArray.push(answer[i].getAttribute('value'));
    answer[i].addEventListener('click', openPresent);
}
```

```css
.option {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.option:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form>
          <div class='option'>
            <input type='radio' id='option1' name="question1" value="option 1">
            <label for='option1'>
              option 1 
            </label><br>
          </div>
          <div class='option'>
            <input type='radio' id='option2' name="question1" value="option 2">
            <label for='option2'>option 2</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class='option'>
            <input type='radio' id='option3' name="question1" value="option 3">
            <label for='option3'>option 3</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class='option'>
            <input type='radio' id='option4' name="question1" value="option 4">
            <label for='option4'>option 4</label><br>
          </div>
        </form>
        
        
        <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 2</p>
                <form>
                    <div class='option'>
                        <input type='radio' id='option1' name="question2" value="option 1">
                        <label for='option1'>
              <div>option 1 </div>
            </label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class='option'>
                        <input type='radio' id='option2' name="question2" value="option 2">
                        <label for='option2'>option 2</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class='option'>
                        <input type='radio' id='option3' name="question2" value="option 3">
                        <label for='option3'>option 3</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class='option'>
                        <input type='radio' id='option4' name="question2" value="option 4">
                        <label for='option4'>option 4</label><br>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `openPresent` with property event, will produce the pointer event in console log. You can use the object of `target` (`event.target`) to search your input element. You can use `querySelector`. After that, you can change the checked to true for make this radio input checked.
You can use this code:

```
function openPresent(event) {
  const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
  for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    answer[i].style.backgroundColor = originalAnswerArray[i];
  }

  const input = event.target.querySelector('input')
  input.checked = true

  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
let i;

let originalAnswerArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
  originalAnswerArray.push(answer[i].getAttribute("value"));
  answer[i].addEventListener("click", openPresent);
}
```

Comment: It just works in only one question. When I click on the next question, the background color in the previous question disappears. So how can  I make the background color in the previous question doesn't disappear.  I mean that when i choose the answer in other questions, the previous answer will be highlight by the background color and doesn't disappear the background color.